# Maximum/Minimum of $f(x)=\sin(2x)+5$ using second derivative test

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

> Find the maximum and minumum values of the function $f(x)=\sin(2x)+5$

It can easily be solved using the basic rules of inequalities. But, how do I solve it using first or second derivative test ?

**My Attempt**

$$
f'(x)=2\cos(2x)=0\implies2x=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\implies x=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{4}\\\implies 2x=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\text{ or }2x=(4n+3)\frac{\pi}{2}\\
f''(x)=-4\sin(2x)
$$

Is it the right way to approach the problem ?

Comment: what are the largest and smallest values of $\sin(2x)$?
what are the largest and smallest values of $5$?

Comment: @danimal i knw this which is mentioned in OP. I am trying to do this using second derivative test

Comment: *Why* to use *second derivatives* when it is utterly trivial that the range of $\sin$ is $[-1,1]$ ?!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanx and i got ur point. but i was just wondering how it can be properly solved that way.

Comment: @ss1729: since the range of $\sin$ is $[-1,1]$, the range of $\sin(2x)+5$ is $[4,6]$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio i mean solved using second derivative test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x)=\sin(2x)+5\\
f'(x)=2\cos(2x)\\
f''(x)=-4\sin(2x)\\
f'(x)=0\implies \cos(2x)=0\implies 2x=(2m+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\implies x=(2m+1)\frac{\pi}{4}\\
2x=(2[2n]+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\text{ or }(2[2n+1]+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\implies2x=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} \text{ or }(4n+3)\frac{\pi}{2}\implies2x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\text{ or }2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}\\
\implies x=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{4} \text{ or }(4n+3)\frac{\pi}{4}\implies2x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\text{ or }2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}\\
f''(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})=-4\sin(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})=-4\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=-4<0\\
f''(2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4})=-4\sin(2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2})=-4\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})=4>0\\
\implies x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4} \text{is local maxima}\\
\implies x=2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4} \text{is local minima}\\
f_{max}=f(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})=\sin(\pi/2)+5=1+5=6\\
f_{min}=f(2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4})=\sin(3\pi/2)+5=-1+5=4\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the derivative of f(x)= sin(2x)+ 5 is f'(x)= 2 cos(2x).  That will be 0 when cos(2x)= 0.  That happens, as you say, when 2x is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{4}$- that is, $2x= (2k+ 1)\frac{\pi}{4}$ so $x= \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{8}$.

Yes, the second derivative is f''(x)= -4 sin(2x).  When $x= \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{8}$ is $2x= \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{4}$.  Those are odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ sine of that goes "+, +, -, -".